# Form Submit From Server Page to Angular Application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I am developing a website with .Net for the backend and Angular for the frontend.
There is a situation when some external website(s) may send form data to our application.
Sample code from external website

```
<body onload="document.myportal.submit()">
     <form name="myportal " action="http://localhost:4200/#/myAngularPage" >
         <input name="value1" type="hidden" value="12345">
         <input name="value2" type="hidden" value="SampleValue2">
     </form>
</body>
```

Now, I need to capture the form values (value1, value2) in Angular somehow, send/redirect it to the backend to validate the data and return the answer back to Angular to proceed working with this website.

Generally, we use action to post data to some API or server endpoint. There we can capture FormData.
I am not sure whether this is possible in HTML/JavaScript/Angular or not.

One way to solve it, is to create a server page/endpoint where form is posted and from there we can redirect to angular application. But I am looking for HTML based solution if possible.

Thanks

Comment: This form will simply result in a URL with get params right..? The only challenge you might have is the # in your angular app. Is there a reason for using that?

Comment: we can't pass value in url, if we get rid of hash. is it possible?

Comment: What is the resulting URL if you submit that form..?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/#/myAngularPage or http://localhost:4200/index.html
I am trying to mimic same behavior which we have for server pages.